# Can a single young bulb of cymbidium mini survive?

Tags: orchids

I had a beautiful yellow cymbidium mini. Once I forgot it in heavy rain and in time it rotted badly. I dried it out, cut the rotten parts and left one old, slightly decayed bulb with the flower, but the decay spread through all remaining healthy parts. Now there is just one healthy little young bulb left, but with 3 starting (1cm) roots.

Does it have any chance to survive? I keep it in very small cup with airy fine substrate, fertilized very little, I spray it with water little twice a day. Can I do more? It is my most beloved one.

Comment: I failed. It looked healthy, but it was rotting from the bottom. The substrate was ok: no mold, moist, but not too much... Seems like it could not support its own roots. After one month, the dead young bulb is still strong, but slightly brownish. Every healthy young bulb from another plant was nicely green.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not soft and squishy it has a chance of resprouting. Even if the roots are chopped off it still can sprout from the nodes given warmth. The color would usually be yellow, brown, to black.

I do not recommend you sprayed the cymbidium with water because most of them require a dry rest between watering (about 3 -14 days depending on where you are and how dry it gets). Spraying them will increase the chance of rotting.

Sprouting from bulbs only work for the majority of standard store brought cymbidium hybrids but not species with no pseudobulbs and it seldomly works for species from the Jensoa subgenera.